# Best international symbol for date range?

Tags: dates, symbols, globalization

From what I know, depending on the country you live, there are different ways of expressing a date range between two dates.

**In Japanese :**

0000/00/00 ~ 0000/00/00

or

0000/00/00 から 0000/00/00 まで

**In English**

0000/00/00 -> 0000/00/00

or

From 0000/00/00 to 0000/00/00

**In French**

0000/00/00 - 0000/00/00

or

Du 0000/00/00 au 0000/00/00

Now the problem is that I would like to use a single convention that can be easily understood in any culture.

Maybe I'm over-thinking it but the "->" symbol might be interpreted as a transformation instead of a range.
I'm also afraid that the "~" might not be understood everywhere the same way (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).

So, what single symbol would you use for a globalized UI?

Comment: On its own no symbol would work. But when the goal of why I'm entering a date is clear, I don't think the symbol really matters. "When are you going on holiday? 0000-00-00 <:> 0000-00-00".

Comment: How about using a localizable string? Simply use the word "till" and translate it like you probably do with the rest of the application. What is this not an option?

Comment: @BartGijssens Because, as you can see in my examples above, the strings can be placed differently depending on the language (ie: Japanese).

Comment: @BartGijssens Sorry, you're right if I use only the symbol version (no wording). But still, I would have to guess the best symbol for every language/culture when a fit-to-all symbol would be more handy.

Comment: That's the problem with fit-to-all solutions: they don't fit all.

Comment: In general, I am all for localization and I agree that you can certainly find a language-specific way of expressing the date range in each language (at least when you use the "verbose" variants with actual words), but then, I also think that the claim that e.g. the format *0000/00/00 - 0000/00/00* is *not* understood everywhere just as well needs to be supported by a reference. After all, as pointed out by Sashko's answer, a straight horizontal line is used and understood in English to express ranges just as well instead of the arrow you suggest above.

Comment: @FranckInJapan: A localizable string, as suggested by Bart Gijssens would work fine if you ask me: `Du {from} au {until}`, `{from} から {until} まで`, `From {from} to {until}`. Just substitute `{from}` and `{to}` and no need to worry about the rest of the string.

Comment: I'm with @O.R.Mapper - There isn't a single understood format.  In the US it tends to be `mm/dd/yyyy`.  In some parts of Europe it's `dd/mm/yyyy`.  In Japan they sometimes use ISO - `YYYY-MM-DD` - if you're lucky; if not, the use "Era" dates (since the start of the current emperor's reign), so you get things like `２６年７月１５日` (that's today).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: This question is *not* about the date format, it is about the *range* format. Also, if you read my comment thoroughly, you will see that I was suggesting that there maybe *is* a single understood format (for ranges).

Comment: @FranckInJapan, It might work to label each field separately (as two nouns rather than one range). Common labels I've seen for hotel booking sites are "check-in date" and "check-out date." For airlines "departure date" and "return date" are common. Such explicit labels can also clear up confusion; for example if I'm checking into a hotel on the 1st and leaving on the 3rd, do I just select the two nights I'm there (1st-2nd)? Or do I select the full range (1st-3rd)?

Answer (score 27):

The international standard ISO 8601 specifies a notation that uses the slash “/” between dates expressed in the year-month-day notation, e.g.

```
2014-07-15/2015-08-01
```

This is the only reasonable *globalized* notation. But it should normally be used only a) internally in data representation when a date range needs to be represented as one string and b) as the rock-bottom fallback default to be used when the locale cannot be inferred or the locale is not supported (and you decide not to use English as default locale).

For *localized* presentations, the trend is to use [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) information or libraries based on it. It specifies, among other things, localizations for different date range notations.

Comment: A slash can be misinterpreted in electronic documentation as "either ... or". Such ambiguities are usually solved by formatted write statements.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's better to put n-dash symbol (U+2013) without spaces on sides. This is typographically right. There is no strict rules about it so you are free to use western tradition.

What is the difference between dash and n-dash, you can read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash